# Exercise 12, Section 3.5 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, proof-writing, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over the field $F$ and let $W$ be a subspace of $V$. If $f$ is a linear
> functional on $W$ , prove that there is a linear functional $g$ on $V$ such that $g(\alpha)= f(\alpha)$ for each $\alpha$ in the subspace W.

We can prove a stronger result:

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over field $F$. If $W\leq V$ and $f\in L(W,Z)$, then $\exists g\in L(V,Z)$ such that $f(\alpha)=g(\alpha)$, $\forall \alpha \in W$.

**My attempt:** Let $\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_m\}$ be basis of $W$. Let $\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_m,\alpha_{m+1},…,\alpha_n\}$ be basis of $V$. By theorem 1 section 3.1, $\exists !g\in L(V, Z)$ such that $g(\alpha_i)=f(\alpha_i)$, $\forall i\in J_m$ and $g(\alpha_i)=0_Z$, $\forall i\in J_n\setminus J_m$. Let $\alpha \in W$. Since $\mathrm{span}(\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_m\})=W$, we have $\alpha=\sum_{i\in J_m}a_i\cdot_V \alpha_i$. Since $f$, $g$ are linear map, we have $f(\alpha)$ $=f(\sum_{i\in J_m}a_i\cdot_V \alpha_i)$ $=\sum_{i\in J_m}a_i\cdot_Z f(\alpha_i)$ $= \sum_{i\in J_m}a_i\cdot_Z g(\alpha_i)$ $= g(\sum_{i\in J_m}a_i\cdot_V \alpha_i)$ $=g(\alpha)$. Hence $f(\alpha)=g(\alpha)$, $\forall \alpha \in W$. **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: If I remember correctly, this problem is also in Linear Algebra Done Right by Sheldon Axler.

Comment: What does $W \le V$ mean?

Comment: @copper.hat $W$ is subspace of $V$.

Comment: In general, if you're using theorems in your particular text, you should really just state those theorems exactly as they are written in the text, explicitly. Not everyone who's helping you will have access to the book you're using. Also, you should try to explain your notation. 

What is $J_m$, for example? It's easy to deduce what that is from the context but you should make such things a bit easier for the reader and, in any regard, it is for your own good as well. Explaining things is part of the game. Anyways, other than that, your proof seems to be fine.

Comment: @user264745 That is not a standard notation.

Comment: @copper.hat I saw that notation in some lecture notes.

Comment: It is clear from context, but it is far from standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **My attempt:**

> Let $\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_m\}$ be basis of $W$. Let $\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_m,\alpha_{m+1},…,\alpha_n\}$ be basis of $V$. By theorem 1 section 3.1, $\exists !g\in L(V, Z)$

What is $Z$?

> such that $g(\alpha_i)=f(\alpha_i)$, $\forall i\in J_m$ and $g(\alpha_i)=0_F$, $\forall i\in J_n\setminus J_m$.

I'm not familiar with this use of $J_m$. Although one can guess that you mean $J_m=\{1,...,m\}$ and $J_n=\{1,...,n\}$, it might be considerate to take the trouble to define $J_n$ and $J_m$ somewhere.

Theorem 1 of section 3.1 states

> - **Theorem 1** Let $V$ be a finite-dimensonal vector space over the field $F$ and let $\{\alpha_1,..., \alpha_n\}$ be an ordered basis for $V$. Let $W$ be a vector space over the same field $F$ and let $\beta_, ..., \beta_n$ be any vectors in $W$. Then there is precisely one linear transformation $T$ from $V$ into $W$ such that $$T\alpha_j=\beta_j, j=1,...,n.
>   $$

so you seem to have decided to choose the $\beta_i$ in the above to be $f(\alpha_1),...,f(\alpha_m),0_F,...0_F$ in the vector space consisting of the scalar field, right?

> Let $\alpha \in W$. Since $\mathrm{span}(\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_m\})=W$, we have $\alpha=\sum_{i\in J_m}a_i\cdot_V \alpha_i$. Since $f$, $g$ are linear map, we have $f(\alpha)$ $=f(\sum_{i\in J_m}a_i\cdot_V \alpha_i)$ $=\sum_{i\in J_m}a_i\cdot_W f(\alpha_i)$ $= \sum_{i\in J_m}a_i\cdot_W g(\alpha_i)$ $= g(\sum_{i\in J_m}a_i\cdot_V \alpha_i)$ $=g(\alpha)$. Hence $f(\alpha)=g(\alpha)$, $\forall \alpha \in W$.

This is a reasonable argument. But since $\alpha \in W$, but $g$ operates over $V$, you might want to use the mappings to $O_F$ which we saw earlier somewhere in the above.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You have pointed out error/typo in my proof. I will edit my post.